# React native code push Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseStaging/compileClasspath':

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I am trying to setup code push to manage the release of my React Native app.

After setting up new buildTypes as per this guide(https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/multi-deployment-testing-android.md)
My project does not sync anymore and I get errors on all of my 3rd party libraries I have installed.

`Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseStaging/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.`

...

and the same for some UnitTest that I guess Gradle added automatically
Unable to resolve dependency for 

`':app@releaseStagingUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.`

I could not find more information in MS Code Push and the example app does not have any 3rd party libraries to look for hints. What is causing this and how to solve this?

my app build.gradle is:

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // Note: CodePush updates should not be tested in Debug mode as they are overriden by the RN packager. However, because CodePush checks for updates in all modes, we must supply a key.
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '""'
        }
        releaseStaging {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '"_acY9ZGwTFpxYTaD71ps0O4o352EB1UmlPoK7"' // fake key
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '"xWEc8lRivDOYHdUAHxBz3hiyiF7hB1WEgPoKQ"' // fake key
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-nfc-manager')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
    implementation project(':react-native-google-signin')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':react-native-code-push')
    implementation project(':react-native-braintree-xplat')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation(project(":react-native-google-signin")){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1' // should be at least 15.0.0 to work with the most recent APIs
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <--- this should be the last line
```

and my android build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 27
        targetSdkVersion = 26
        supportLibVersion = "27.0.2"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4' // <--- use this version or newer
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1' // <--- use this version or newer

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.4'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it! my 3rd party libraries did not know what to do with the stagingRelease buildtype so I needed to provide a fallback version like so:

```
buildtypes {
  ...
  releaseStaging {
    ...
    matchingFallbacks = ["release"]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your android build.gradle file by using below code:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven {
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope, it will help.